# Mobile analytic using selenium and appium

Tags: selenium, testing, analytics, appium, browsermob-proxy

I'm able to do analytics testing using browsermob and selenium in my previous project, but 'm not able to do same with mobile web using appium and selenium.
Though m able to start the proxy server but not able to bind it with my mobile web.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm closing this question as i got the answer. FYI its same as for desktop only we have to set ours  mobile proxy to same before starting the test.

Comment: Do you know how to capture traffic using ios Simulator